# Local domains stop working

Tags: apache2, localhost

I have several sites configured in my local machine. I use Ubuntu 12.04 for long time and had these sites working well. Only few days ago from some reason they all stopped working.

When I navigate to 127.0.1.1 I see the default site (`/var/www/index.html`).
However, when I try to access some other local domain I get this screen:

```
This webpage is not available

ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

And in details I get:

```
The server at www.wordpress.localhost can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed.
```

I tried to restart apache server, and also stop and start it. I have the feeling that when I start it it takes much less than usual. Anyway, this is what I see:

```
/data/www $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
                                                                                        [ OK ]
```

Any idea??

===== EDIT ======
Here is a part of my `/etc/hosts` file, in case you see something strange here:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   xxx-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC

127.0.1.1   www.wordpress.localhost
127.0.0.1   www.test-site.localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: A very first thought/obvious thing but better to ask: Did you by chance populate the `/etc/hosts` file by yourself earlier and had it modified by an update? Try cat /etc/hosts in the terminal and see if it contains anything useful? I use hosts to store IP addresses in my local network, so perhaps that would also help with your localhost issue.

Comment: No, I do not see anything strange in `hosts` file.